# WPF Application Update Best Practices - Architectural Explanation

Tags: c#, wpf, architecture, desktop-application, auto-update

This question is not only applicable to WPF but other programming language as well but I will for my sake and other ask the experts in the house for professional advice.

I am starting an desktop application in WPF c# and the application modules is subjected to updates practically everyday.

Taking WPF C# as a case study, can anyone just give an architectural explanation on designing such application.

Take for example, the application can perform accounting, auditing and so on. the main window UI and other UI and all application logic in the application is subjected to change based on daily update.

The update task should be performed in the background and will startup when the computer starts. The update must not interfere with the program when the user is making use of it but update installation should be performed when the application is not running or prompt the user about it.

I will appreciate contributions from experts in the house.

Thanks

Comment: There are entire books to answer that

Comment: Can we start from somewhere or give references? I will much appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing here is a good fit for looking into using MEF.

Manage Extensibility Framework will allow you to make use of non-statically referenced library files that adhere to a standard interface that you define.  Since they are not statically referenced you can replace these library files within an installed application without the need for recompiling the rest of the application.

In these terms any "replaceable" logic should be placed within these MEF'd libraries and treated like plugins.  That way you can updating them whenever required.

As for handling the detection and download of new version of plugins that will be something you have to roll on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am looking into this MEF right now and I think this is a starting point, Kudos man, I can start from here.

Comment: If you have ever build this type of application before, How do you handle the download and overwrite procedures. Although I can squeeze out a working solution from my head but a tested and working solution will aid my RAD.

Comment: That is going to be pretty involved as you cannot unload dlls from an app domain which makes over-writing dlls that have been loaded into memory problematic.  MEF does have a feature that allows rebuilding the catalogs but I'm not sure how that functions under the hood.  The biggest problem will be overwriting the in-use dlls.

Comment: Ok, I guess I have to sit down and deal with this. But at least giving me this hint, the rest should be my problem. God bless you man, really appreciate.